# iFrame properties don't get updated through JS DOM

Tags: javascript, iframe

Another noob question, this one is quite a mystery to me.

I'm trying to inject a JS code, and making use of iFrame for this.

Test url -> http://ultimateclassicmovies.com/horror/the-brain-that-wouldnt-die/

Here I initially created a hidden iFrame

and then i'm injecting into it a new JS code:
document.getElementById('movie_loader').src = 'jwplayer.php?id=5');

and making it visible:
document.getElementById('movie_loader').visibility = 'visible';

but nothing happens as you can see. both SRC and VISIBILIY props aren't updated.

The same happened when I used the DISPLAY property.

Any idea?

Comment: Please show your code in here.

Comment: Also, do you get any js errors in your browser error console?

Comment: Take a look at this, maybe this can help you to find a solution between show/hide ways: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712292/iframe-cssvisibility-hidden-not-working-in-google-chrome (you are missing ".style " before visibility and display commands)

Answer (score 2):

You're missing 'style'.

```
document.getElementById('movie_loader').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

or better, use "display" rather than "visibility (use `display: none;` to start):

```
 document.getElementById('movie_loader').style.display = 'block';
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error on the first line with an extra `)` on the end, and you need to add `.style` on the second line, like this:

```
document.getElementById('movie_loader').src = 'jwplayer.php?id=5';
document.getElementById('movie_loader').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Styles on an element are stored as an object under [`.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/STYLE), not as direct properties.

Though, once you fix this... it can't find that `jwplayer.php` file, it's a 404, so you need to adjust the path somehow...I'm not sure exactly where on your site it's located, but it's not found at: http://ultimateclassicmovies.com/horror/the-brain-that-wouldnt-die/jwplayer.php?id=5