# $('iframe').css('visibility','hidden') not working in Google chrome

Tags: jquery, security, google-chrome, iframe, visibility

I am using something like

```
$('ul li').find('iframe').css({'visibility':'visible'});
```

which works fine In Firefox and Opera,

console error:

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL file:///D:/Configuracion/Documents%20and%20Settings/TNMC000/Escritorio/player/roundabout/js/round1.htm from frame with URL http://www.youtube.com/embed/hurnoKLuBD8. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Test URL: http://toniweb.us/vimeo-like/js/images.htm

any idea?

-EDIT-

I fixed it using

```
.invisible{ text-indent:-9999px }
```

and

```
<div class="iframe"><iframe></iframe></div>
```

and

```
$('ul li').find('.iframe').addClass('invisible');
```

But still would like to know how to fix it working with only the iframe.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors in the console?

Comment: I don't see your error while running scripts in the chrome console `$('h1').css({'visibility':'hidden'});` works correctly on stackoverflow. Are you sure that all the rest is the same between chrome and other browsers?

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)/[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/)?

Comment: i am appling it to an <iframe> ok, i will post in in jsfiddle. Edited with the console error.

Comment: Are you using a local web server? Or does it say `file://` in your address bar? ಠ_ಠ

Comment: i am executing the file from my computer and it says file:// in the adress bar. i Was trying to put a simple example but is easier to share a link to the script. It's on the question. thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are issues with actually making iframes invisible (i.e. using `visibility:hidden` or `display:none`). 
But you can make them disappear by being small enough

```
$('ul li').find('iframe').css({"height":"0", "width":"0", "border":"none"});
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your input. but do you think that would work for a youtube iframe, for example?

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a bit dated, but I just ran into the same problem. My solution was

```
css( 'opacity', 0 )
```

Comment: still you can click on it ;)

Answer (score -1):

The object map should work just fine but if you're only setting a single style it may be easier to skip the object map completely. Try this:

```
$('ul li').find('.titThumb').css('visibility', 'visible');
$('ul li').find('.titIframe').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Comment: I don't mind downvotes but I'd appreciate a comment to explain. We all want to improve ourselves here.

Comment: You're probably getting downvotes because changing the way `.css()` is called is not going to change anything. Both ways are correct. Your answer should be a comment.