# Visibility attribute stopped working in chrome for me

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I created a web app some months ago and tested it working fine in ie, ff & chrome.

i went to add something last night and noticed that my hide iframe function is no longer working in chrome.

If i inspect the element i can see the attribute is indeed changing, but the iframe is not hidden.

```
function hideIFrame(){
    document.getElementById("myFrame").style.visibility="hidden";
    self.focus();
}

function showIFrame(){
    document.getElementById("myFrame").style.visibility="visible";
}
```

the myFrame div starts off hidden. and is made visible successfully but when the visibility is changed to hidden chrome is not hiding it, ff and ie do hide it still.

any idea why?

**The FIX:**

```
function hideIFrame(){
    document.getElementById("myFrame").style.visibility="hidden";
    document.getElementById("myFrame").style.opacity=0;
    self.focus();
}

function showIFrame(){
    document.getElementById("myFrame").style.visibility="visible";
    document.getElementById("myFrame").style.opacity=1;
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a jsfiddle. There must be something else going on…

Comment: Having the same issue. Can you find a bug entry on Chromium?

EDIT: found this entry: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=301376 

Can you confirm the bug only occurs on pages that embed flash content?

Comment: @Gyum Fox My page did embed flash yes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are problems with iframe visibility toggling ([$('iframe').css('visibility','hidden') not working in google chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712292/iframe-cssvisibility-hidden-not-working-in-google-chrome)). If you want it to disappear, use height, width:0. If you want it to simply be invisible, use opacity:0.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get your problem. May be you should post some more codes where you are calling the function. Here is a sample code works well in chrome.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hideIFrame(){
document.getElementById("myFrame").style.visibility="hidden";
self.focus();
}

function showIFrame(){
document.getElementById("myFrame").style.visibility="visible";
}
</script>

<input type="button" onclick="hideIFrame()" value="hide"/>
<input type="button" onclick="showIFrame()" value="show"/>

<iframe id="myFrame">

</iframe>
```

Comment: yes your right, i added to a fiddle and this works in chrome http://jsfiddle.net/SKFeC/ but for some reason not in my app

Answer (score 1):

use display.none instead

```
    function hideIFrame(){ 
document.getElementById("myFrame").style.display="none";
    self.focus();
}

function showIFrame(){
    document.getElementById("myFrame").style.display="inline";
   //or document.getElementById("myFrame").style.display="block";
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I will just use JS onload to hide the element and I will be able to  use JS to toggle `visibility="visible"`

```
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("newDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";
}
function showHidden() {
  document.getElementById("newDiv").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```