# Flash contents are not getting hidden in Chrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have asp.net page on which i showed Flash Contents using:

```
<object id="FlashFile" width="800" height="240">
<embed src="images/animation.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="800"
 height="240"></embed>
</object>
```

and after clicking some linkbutton say "Read More" i want this flash to be hidden and showing some popup javascript.
I used

```
document.getElementById("FlashFile").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Before showing the popup javascript.

It is working on IE and Mozilla but not on Chrome.
In chrome the Flash contents are still shown with full visibility.
Can anyone tell me what should be done.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following underneath your visibility line:

```
document.getElementById("FlashFile").style.opacity=0;
```

Found this example from this post here: 
[Visibility attribute stopped working in chrome for me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12767165/visibility-attribute-stopped-working-in-chrome-for-me)

Comment: It is not working yet...Actually in flash contents i shown images one by one. I think at first while loading Javascript it is geeting disabled but when image changes it shows again.. but one to say that it the single swf file only..

Answer (score 0):

I'd wrap it all in a `div` and then hide that.

```
<div id="flashContent">
<object id="FlashFile" width="800" height="240">
<embed src="images/animation.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="800" height="240"></embed>
</object></div>
```

js:

```
document.getElementById("flashContent").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

Comment: It is still not getting hidden. Flash contents gets overlap on Java script popup. One thing to mention that Flash contents are on Master page and i am hiding them in child page.

Comment: say i have services.aspx for which i have MasterPage.Master as master page and hiding line are in Services.aspx.