# how to make div+iframe disappear in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, html, iframe

I am trying to make a div containing an iframe appear/disappear when a checkbox is selected/unselected.

Here is a quick demo [http://jsfiddle.net/bhS9T/](http://jsfiddle.net/bhS9T/1/)

```
$(function () {
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
    switch (this.id) {
        case 'video':
            if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                $(".video").css("visibility", "visible");
            } else {
                $(".video").css("visibility", "hidden");
            }
            break;
    };
});

    .video {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    display:block;
    background-color: blue;
    border: solid red 8px;
    padding: 30px;
    background-image: none;
}
```

In safari the video disappears with the div, which is great. However, in chrome the video remains. Can anyone help?

Comment: Use opacity instead of visibility. Check this:- http://jsfiddle.net/dE7HE/

Comment: And this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7712292/iframe-cssvisibility-hidden-not-working-in-google-chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing to .show() / .hide() works.

```
$(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function () {
        switch (this.id) {
            case 'video':
                if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                    $(".video").show();
                } else {
                    $(".video").hide();
                }
                break;
        };
    });
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/corey_rothwell/kA2G6/